# Laravel: Automatically Create Slug from Title Using Create & Validate Methods

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I want to automatically create a slug and save it to the database based on the title entered into a form.  Currently, this is how my controller is set up:

```
  public function store(News $id) {
    News::create($this->validateArticle());
    return redirect('/news');
  }

  public function validateArticle() {
    return request()->validate([
      'title' => 'required',
      'excerpt' => 'nullable',
      'body' => 'nullable'
    ]);
  }
```

How can I modify this code so that I automatically generate a slug based off of the title?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is another option of how to do it. Or you could use Observer to observe the crating method like so `news->slug= Str::slug($request->title);`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $news= new News();
    $news->title= $request->title; 
    $news->slug= Str::slug($request->title);
    $news->excerpt= $request->excerpt;
    $news->body= $request->body;
    $news->save();
    return redirect('/news');
}
```

Make use you  import Str `use Illuminate\Support\Str;`